# Iterative SQL Query

Tags: sql, hana

I have a tricky requirement with a binary tree

This is how my data looks like

```
ID     IDNEXT
1A       2E
3D       4A
2E       6F
6F       3D
4A
```

My OutPut should be in this fashin

```
ID     IDNEXT
1A      2E
2E      6F
6F      3D
3D      4A
4A
```

Based on the current IDNEXT should me mynext ID and we i should continue like this till the end  and depth is unknown

Any suggestions

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any column can represnt the order?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, SAP HANA provides [Hierarchy-Functions](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4f9859d273254e04af6ab3e9ea3af286/2.0.03/en-US/f29c70e984254a6f8df76ad84e78f123.html) that allow for very efficient processing of hierarchy-data that has been encoded in tables via the "node"/"parent node" scheme.

The requirement of this question can be stated as *"traverse the directed graph depth-first and return the visited nodes in the order of visit"*.

With the hierarchy functions that is easy to do:

```
create column table con (ID nvarchar(2) not null
                       , IDNEXT nvarchar(2) not null);
/*
ID     IDNEXT
1A       2E
3D       4A
2E       6F
6F       3D
4A
*/

insert into con values ('1A', '2E');
insert into con values ('3D', '4A');
insert into con values ('2E', '6F');
insert into con values ('6F', '3D');
insert into con values ('4A', '');

SELECT   
     hierarchy_rank AS rank,
     node_id,
     parent_id
FROM HIERARCHY (
    SOURCE (SELECT  ID  as "NODE_ID"
                  , IDNEXT as "PARENT_ID" 
            FROM con)
    START WHERE IDNEXT =''
    )
ORDER BY
    hierarchy_rank desc;

/*
RANK    NODE_ID PARENT_ID
5       1A      2E       
4       2E      6F       
3       6F      3D       
2       3D      4A       
1       4A               
*/
```

This approach benefits from

- expressiveness of how the hierarchy is created based on the table data and what computation should be done with the hierarchy
- efficient (both space and time) implementation of the hierarchy processing in SAP HANA instead of emulating the functionality via SQL functions. This comes in especially handy when the same hierarchy should be reused as the structure gets cached automatically.

The biggest *hurdle* with these special functions probably is that they require to think precisely about the hierarchy/graph one wants to define. Fortunately, the **SAP HANA Academy** provides some tutorial [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7jUzCtxTnkA) to follow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Hana, but in standard SQL you could use recursive CTE (common table expressions).

The following example had been tested with PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE links(id VARCHAR(10), idnext VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO links(id, idnext) values('1a','2e'), ('3d','4a'), ('2e','6f'), ('6f', '3d');

WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT id, idnext FROM links WHERE id='1a'   -- the first node  
  UNION ALL    
  SELECT links.id, links.idnext 
    FROM links  
    JOIN cte 
    ON  links.id = cte.idnext
) 
SELECT * FROM cte;
```

The result:

```
 id | idnext 
----+--------
 1a | 2e
 2e | 6f
 6f | 3d
 3d | 4a
```

Comment: Unfortunately HANA doesn’t support Recursive .. I think we have to go with cursor and loop’s any suggestion with that

Comment: Is it possible to use cursors and loops

Comment: It's correct that HANA does not support recursive common table expressions or function/procedure calls. However, it does support *hierarchy* functions that can be used to process such a self-referencing data set. 
I would not recommend using cursors or loops here.